# Plotting lines between values in a 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d numpy array that consists of blocks of contiguous values. [Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALB1Y.png) I would like to plot lines around the values. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean lines around _every_ point? You can do that with `plt.pcolor(two_dim_array, shading='faceted')`. If you want lines only between regions of same values (your example suggests that a bit), I think this might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I am indeed trying to put a border around regions of the same value. I was afraid it would be more complicated than it seems.

Comment: You may use a contour plot to draw the edges. If necessary, you may then increase the resolution of the contour as seen in this question: [Can matplotlib contours match pixel edges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892203/can-matplotlib-contours-match-pixel-edges).